# Update a document in an array in MongoDB using webMethods

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a requirement to a particular document in the arrayList, the sample JSON string for that is

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b9339502be203f6b476664"),
    "_docType" : "Test",
    "type" : "mongoUpdate",

```
"createdDateTime" : "2017-03-03 09:12:53.080",
"contacts" : [ 
    {

        "firstName" : "FirstName",
        "lastName" : "LastName",
        "email" : "someName@email.com",
        "contactType" : "Business.",
        "phoneNumber" : "1234567890",           
        "createdDateTime" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",            
        "lastModifiedDTM" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",
       }, 
   {

        "firstName" : "FirstName2",
        "lastName" : "LastName2",
        "email" : "someName@email.com2",
        "contactType" : "Business2.",
        "phoneNumber" : "1234567890",           
        "createdDateTime" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",            
        "lastModifiedDTM" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",
       },
    {

        "firstName" : "FirstName3",
        "lastName" : "LastName3",
        "email" : "someName@email.com3",
        "contactType" : "Business.3",
        "phoneNumber" : "12345678903",           
        "createdDateTime" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",            
        "lastModifiedDTM" : "2017-03-03 09:13:04.229",
       }
]
```

}

Say I have to update one of the occurrence in the above json.
 I have used the $set operation to update the above array and  when I see the content in the mongo db I see the the whole array is replaced by single occurrence of contact.

the update command which I have used is

{$set:{"contacts":[{"firstName":"test0103)12","lastName":"test0103","email":"test0103","contactType":"test0103","phoneNumber":"test0103","createdDateTime":"test0103"}]}}

after executing this I see that the whole array list of 3 is replaced with the single instance of  contacts.

and at the end I have the output as
"contacts" : [ 
    {

```
    "firstName" : "test0103)12",
    "lastName" : "test0103",
    "email" : "test0103",
    "contactType" : "test0103",
    "phoneNumber" : "test0103",           
    "createdDateTime" : "test0103"           

   }]
```

Comment: Thats because you don't update array of objects like you are doing. Operations on objects inside an array are done differently in mongoose and there are many questions related to it which you can discover.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code

First find the document using _id. here collection I took is user

```
`  User.findOne({'_id': 58b9339502be203f6b476664},(err,res) => {
       if(res.contacts.length > 0){
          var contacts = res.contacts;
          var contactsList = [];
          var contactobject = {};
         // suppose you want to update the contact with firstname -   FirstName2
          contacts.map((contact,key)=>{
                   if(contact.firstName  == "firstName2"{

                       contactobject.firstName = "Your updated name";
                       contactobject.lastName = "Your updated name";
                      // similary all values you want to update
                      // Then push to an array after updating new data
                      contactsList.push(contactObject);

                  }
                else {
                    // if not the required contact to update
                    // simply push
                     contactsList.push(contact);

                 }

           })
```

// After the map function , now update the new contacts

```
        User.update({email:email},
                             {$set:{contacts: contactsList}},(err,result) => {
                                      User.findOne({'_id':res._id}).then(updateuser => {
                               resolve(updateuser);
                                         })
                                     })
       }
```

}) `

Try this , It works

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't not help me as I need something with webMethods code. So I have done changes accordingly and its working.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't not help me as I need something with webMethods code.
 So I have done changes accordingly and its working. 
 I have first fetched the contacts from the mongo and then looped over the retrieved results from mongo
 and looped over my input list
 
 if they are equal i am ignoring them and if they are not equal then i am forming a query
 say for exmaple "contacts.$.firstName":"inputValue" and similarly for all the values in the list.
 
 then after i get the whole list i am doing a $set which will replace the values with the new ones.